# Change format of comment that is posted to wall using the Facebook comment box?

Tags: facebook-social-plugins

Currently when an user posts a comment on my site using `fb:comments` and checks the `"Post to profile"`. The post that is shared on users Facebook wall shows

- the page title
- the source (url)

How can I make it also share the other `og:meta` tags? So I'd love it to take the description as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come so far that, when an user comments on a page using the like button comment box popup all the needed data goes to facebook in the format i wanted. Comments on the same pages using the comment box have a different formatting. I guess it is by design from facebook.